# Get json response via restful services, front-end or back-end?

Tags: jquery, rest

I am trying to get json format data via restful services. There are two ways to do it:
1. using jquery $.ajax to send the request in view(front-end)
2. using web services(WS) from play framework and then pass the result to front-end
Which one is better?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends on the specifics of your application.  There's a lot of factors at play.  Can you give more context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use jquery the service has to respect at list one of this items:

- Be on the same domain
- Expose the XDR headers
- Expose the service in jsonp

If none of this is possible you have to run the request in the backend.

Other reasons to do not use jquery is to do not expose oauth Keys (if the service uses it)

A reason to use jquery when is possible is that it does not require extra code and you reduce the load on the server itself.